# I want to add errorbars showing standard deviation in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, errorbar

This is my code so far and I want to add errorbars showing the standard deviation for the bins to my histogram and I have no clue how I can add that.
The y-axis is relative frequency and x-axis is size

```
data = data.frame(Feret = sample(0:1200,100))

data %\>%
 ggplot(aes(x=Feret))+
 theme_bw()+
 xlim(0,1200)+
 geom_histogram(color = "black",binwidth = 20,aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..))))+
 scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
 labs(x="Size",y="Relative frequency %")
```

Comment: Note that use of `..count..` and similar variables is deprecated.  See "Other breaking changes" [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/ggplot2-3-4-0/).

Comment: What do you mean "the standard deviation of the bins"? I’m not sure what you’re asking for is meaningful.